# same function for same elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a function that, when you click in a textarea, it will slide down a button.

However, I have multiple textareas on the page with the same class and the problem is that if you click on any of the textareas, *all* of them will slide down the button.

How can I make it so that it only slides down on the textarea element that you click on, and not the others?

Here's a quick JSFiddle I made: [**http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6100/**](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6100/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="well">
    <textarea style="width:462px" placeholder="Comment..."></textarea>
    <button  class="btn btn-primary btn-toggle" type="button">Post</button>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="well">
    <textarea style="width:462px" placeholder="Comment..."></textarea>
    <button  class="btn btn-primary btn-toggle" type="button">Post</button>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("textarea").click(function(){
  $(".btn-toggle").slideDown();
});

$(document).click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  if($(e.target).parents(".well").length == 0){
    $(".btn-toggle").slideUp();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have to find the elements relative to the element that was clicked.

`$(this)` is the element that was clicked, and `siblings()` finds elements that are siblings.

http://jsfiddle.net/P9nMq/

```
$("textarea").click(function(){
   $(this).siblings('.btn-toggle').slideDown();
});

$(document).click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    if($(e.target).parents(".well").length == 0){
        $(this).find('.btn-toggle').slideUp();
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, that was super quick. I'll mark your reply as solved when I can (12 minutes).

Answer (score 1):

How about instead of relying on a class lookup, use the event target:

```
$("textarea").click(function(evtTarget){
  $(evtTarget.target).parent().find($(".btn-toggle")).slideDown();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/paulprogrammer/MgcDU/6103/

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet selects **all** the buttons:

```
 $(".btn-toggle").slideUp();
```

You should replace it with this:

```
 $(this).siblings(".btn-toggle").slideUp();
```

**Update**
I would rewrite your script with these lines :

```
$(".well").('focus blur', "textarea", function(e){
    $(this) 
        .siblings(".btn-toggle")
            .stop(true, true)
            .slideToggle();
});
```

The advantage is that you delegate the events on the same parent of the two targeted elements and that you do not rely on any `click` event handlers.